# Deformation Under High Pressure

Tags: finite-element-method, deformation

If a FEA model suggests that a material deforms in a certain way for a max pressure of 1e+11, 1e+13, 1e+15, can it be suggested that the same "direction" of deformation would be true?

I have been modeling an explicitly dynamic system for which pressure is built up in 100ns to a set maximum pressure, incident on a material. I have noticed a specific pattern of deformation for an increase in max pressure, as mentioned above, although for 1e+19 the material is in a complete mess, with parts being stretched in many directions, indicating a complete breakdown of the model.

My Question therefore is: **Would the deformation continue to change in the same way at this pressure (1e+19) or would it truly be a mess of particles?**